# Is a mobile phone number in itself an information that can be utilized by hackers etc?

Tags: android, vulnerability, phone

I recently installed Tinder, and I saw that the app warns about sharing your phone number to avoid being hacked.

I also noticed certain obviously fake profiles pressing for getting a phone number or skype id.

But I don't really understand what is the security issue besides getting unwanted whatsapp messages or calls that you can block.

Is there any way that someone can exploit a phone number itself besides a person in ignorance falling into social engineering hacks by answering personal question to a person who thinks is a romantic match? Or is it country dependent what kind of info a mobile number itself reveals?

Comment: most likely they are not trying to hack you but just phish you in a place where their tinder account won't get banned because the tinder staff can't see the messages

Comment: "the app warns about sharing your phone number to avoid being hacked" -- what's the actual text?

Comment: @schroeder: The text in the app says: "Are you ready to share your phone? Be cautious to avoid getting hacked"

Comment: What an odd and unhelpful warning ... I think they are just applying a catch-all term. The biggest risk is social engineering. I wouldn't interpret that message as talking about a technical exploit against a machine vulnerability.

Comment: @schroeder: You mean calling the person and trying to extract information that could be useful for hacking purposes right? Is there some info that can be useful to such a person that most people think it is safe to share?

Comment: Not necessarily calling to hack ... Like you said: social engineering, sending WhatsApp phishing messages, etc.